# javascript oncut bug?

Tags: javascript

In this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<input id="a"/>
<input id="b"/>
<script>
var a=document.getElementById("a");
var b=document.getElementById("b");
a.addEventListener("cut",function(e){
    b.value=a.value;
    //the line above is not working as expected!
    //neither does this (as per tjm's answer): b.value=a.value.substr(0,a.selectionStart);
},true);

</script>
</body>
```

When I do a cut in text-box-a, I want text-box-b to have the same value as text-box-a.. but it's not working. does anyone have any solution to this problem?

I need the solution to work in IE9.

(3 answers so far though none of them worked.. i can't believe we can't do this in javascript.. this is like one of the less-common-but-still-common stuff that we need ain't it?)

Comment: When I test on jsfiddle, when I cut the text in box A it appears in box B. What are you wanting to do? http://jsfiddle.net/keroger2k/X9QwR/

Comment: Which browser are you using? This code will not work in Firefox because `a` is not defined -- you have to use `document.getElementById('a').addEv...`.

Comment: @Kyle in A i type "asd", then i select the "s" and do a cut. now the value in A is "ad". However the value in B is "asd". i want the value of B be "ad" (which is the value of A)

Comment: @brianpeiris question updated =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works as you want it to.

```
<script>
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");

a.addEventListener("cut", function(e) {

    var s = a.value;
    b.value = s.substr(0,a.selectionStart) + s.substr(a.selectionEnd);

}, false);

</script>
```

Comment: @ShenHong. Ok updated my answer. I *think* this one does actually work. I hope so anyway.

Comment: both yours and Kyle's method works. btw can you comment on which method do you personally feel is "better" ?

Comment: @ShenHong. Glad it worked. I would prefer my method with the proviso that `selectionStart/End` are available on all the browsers you wish to support. I haven't really used them before so I can't tell you, so I think it is important to find that out. The `setTimeout` method introduces a level of uncertainty as to whether it will always work, but may be a necessary fallback if you find my method doesn't work everywhere you need it too. An `aftercut` event would be ideal but as you say, there isn't one, so for the time being I think this is an OK compromise (hack!).

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not the best solution, but it works.  You can probably lower the timeout to make it a bit better.  This is a total hack.  I just don't know anything else to advise.

```
a.addEventListener("cut", function(evnt) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("b").value = evnt.srcElement.value;
    },100);
}, true);
```

Comment: both yours and tjm's method works. btw can you comment on which method do you personally feel is "better" ?

Comment: Better to try to avoid setTimeout IMHO

Comment: I agree.  tjm's is better.  I had no idea about selectionStart/End.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
a.addEventListener("beforecut",function(e){
    b.value=a.value;
});
```

Comment: i've tried the beforecut, but it's not working. what i want is "aftercut" but there isn't such an event

Comment: Finally understand your purpose. I think tjm's method will work. :)